# how to get lengths of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames with different lengths. How do I get the length of each data frame? I tried `nrow` function but it returns "NULL".

Comment: probably just `lapply(list_of_dfs, nrow)`

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lengths` is for getting the `length` of `list` of `vectors`.  Here, we need the `nrow` or `ncol`

```
sapply(lst, nrow)
sapply(lst, ncol)
```

depending upon what the OP considers as `length`

Comment: how can I change the whole data frames' lengths to the maximum length of all the lengths and put NA for shorter lengths?

Comment: @NOA11120 Did you meant the lengths as `nrow`

Comment: yes the lengths as nrow. my aim is to View or export to excel my list of data frames of different lengths. so I though to change the lengths of all of the dataframes to the maximum length and put NA in rows for shorter dataframes, and  then I can View it

Comment: You can do `mx <- max(sapply(lst, nrow));lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) if(nrow(x) < mx) {x[(mx - nrow(x) + 1):mx, ] <- NA; x} else x)`

Comment: Dear akrun! I changed it to- lapply(peak_data, function(x) if(nrow(x) < mx)
  {x[(nrow(x) + 1):mx,] <- NA; y} else x) and it what I wanted! Thank you so much!